# Animate letters in a label or text view

Tags: ios, swift, animation, text

I need to perform an effect like this in my app:

[image: letters effect]

How can I do this? I need to animate single letters in the text and not the entire label. I'm using Swift.

**EDIT** (*more details*):

I need to animate the letters from right to left using a sort of spring damping (like UIView animation), but I don't know how to achieve this. The most important part of this animation is the first one, where the letters enter from left to right with a variable space between the first ones and the others

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/android1989/CharacterText . May this help you .

Comment: Goto http://swiftyeti.com and you'll find lots of interesting code. Just what your looking for; although not for the faint hearted!

Answer (score 0):

A while back I asked a similar question and got this reply from

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4754400/chris-gulley

A very clever piece of code indeed.

```
class Timer {
typealias TimerFunction = (Int)->Bool
private var handler: TimerFunction
private var i = 0

init(interval: NSTimeInterval, handler: TimerFunction) {
    self.handler = handler
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "timerFired:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc
private func timerFired(timer:NSTimer) {
    if !handler(i++) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let text: NSAttributedString = {
    let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
    return NSAttributedString(string: "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away ...", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 120, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-20))
    self.view.addSubview(textView)

    let _ = Timer(interval: 0.1) {i -> Bool in
        textView.attributedText = self.text.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: i+1))
        return i + 1 < self.text.string.characters.count
    }
}
}
```

[Displaying text one character at a time in swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456304/displaying-text-one-character-a-time-in-swift-2-0/33462719#33462719)

Comment: This is very nice, but I need something more animated, a sort of UIView.animateWithDuration... usingSpringWithDamping to animate the letters from right to left (and then left to right), but I really don't know how to do