# swift 2 animateWithDuration not repeating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, animatewithduration

I have been trying to get this animation to work for hours but to no avail. Here is  a snapshot. So I have a price label that shows current price of the product, which is in a custom collectionviewcell. When the `collectionView:willDisplayCell` is called, I then call the below method on my custom collection view cell called animateDiscountPrice.

The animation i am trying to achieve is to add the compare_at price character by character to the end of the current price label. I tried setting the REPEAT option along with repeat count but the animation block is called only once and then the completion block is immediately called. There is no animation basically.

```
func animateDiscountPrice()
    {
        let priceText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.priceLabel.attributedText!)
        let originalPriceText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.priceLabel.attributedText!)
        let offset = priceText.length
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            if let compareAtString : String = self.productData["compare_at_price_min"] as? String {
                let compareAtPrice = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$\(compareAtString)", attributes: myAttribute )
                var i = 0
                let count = compareAtString.characters.count+1
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(count), delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction, .CurveLinear],
                            animations: {
                                UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float(count))

                                priceText.appendAttributedString(compareAtPrice.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(i, 1)))
                                    priceText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: discountColor, range: NSMakeRange(offset, i+1))
                                    self.priceLabel.attributedText = priceText
                                    i = i + 1
                            },
                            completion: { (finished) in
                                if(finished)
                                {
                                    originalPriceText.appendAttributedString(compareAtPrice)
                                    originalPriceText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: discountColor, range: NSMakeRange(offset, compareAtPrice.length))
                                    //self.priceLabel.attributedText = originalPriceText
                                }
                            }
                    )
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the log lines I can see the animation is called only once for each cell being displayed, and calling completion methods afterwards.

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456304/displaying-text-one-character-at-a-time-in-swift-2-0/33462719#33462719

Comment: Thank you, different approach but solves the problem.